# Correct way to open a new window in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

I have a rather large app made in Appcelerator Titanium, which I've not ported from the SDK version 3.2  because the Ti.Ui.Window's "url" property has been removed, which my application uses extensively. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find the new, correct way to do this. The info I'm finding out there does only point to the removal of the url property, or suggests that I should move to Alloy (which at the moment is not doable for me as it would require a complete rewrite of the app). Can anyone point me to an example of the right way this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using Alloy, then it's really a two step process. First you need to get the handle to the window. That is usually done with Ti.UI.createWindow (see http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-method-createWindow). Now that you have a reference to the window, you simply open it. So,

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({title: 'My first window'});
win.open();
```

Documentation on the window object is here.  http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window

If you have windows defined in other js files. ie. myWindow.js, then you can use require to get the js window. Have the code in your window return a "Window" object, then open that.

ie. myWindow.js

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({title: 'Window from another file'});
return win;
```

Then in your calling file, don't use url, require the window:

```
var myNewWindow = require('myWindow');
myNewWindow.open();
```

You can see information about calling require here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require

Hope that helps.

Ray

Comment: I've been experimenting with something similar to this, but I'm not sure if it's the best practice. I put my second-window code in a CommonJS module. I require() the module, and call a single exported function from it. The exported function creates the window and handles all of its logic. Is there a downside to doing it like this?

Comment: It's really the same thing. So doesn't matter. Big thing is changing to Alloy when you get a chance and a new project. Much easier and more maintainable for projects.